# Python Web scraping using selenium to extract tables data

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to web scrape this website using PYTHON selenium.

`www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=Z74.SI`

But the selenium seem to hang and not loading.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver as web 
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

import time

driver.get("http://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=Z74.SI")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
time.sleep(5)
print(driver.page_source)
```

I am interested in the table as shown below.
What is wrong with my code? I am not able to get any output.

[image: INTERESTED IN THIS TABLE]

Comment: Please edit your question. give the code, not screenshot.

Comment: What do you mean `print correctly`? What is the "correct" way for you to print a table?

Comment: I am new with python Selenium, How to get an output from the website? I am interested in the table above but I am not able to do so.